# A C++ template function for doing multi-indexing a sequence

Tags: c++, template

The idea behind the below code is that I can index a sequence with a sequence of indices and get a `std::vector` of the indexed elements:

**multi_index.hpp**

```
#ifndef NET_CODERODDE_UTIL_MULTI_INDEX_HPP
#define NET_CODERODDE_UTIL_MULTI_INDEX_HPP

#include <algorithm>
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>

namespace net::coderodde::util {

    template<typename IteratorIndex>
    using index_type =
    typename std::iterator_traits<IteratorIndex>::value_type;

    template<typename IteratorElem>
    using element_count_type =
    typename std::iterator_traits<IteratorElem>::difference_type;

    template<typename IteratorElem>
    using element_type =
    typename std::iterator_traits<IteratorElem>::value_type;

    ////  ///////////////////////////////////////////////
     // Throws an exception if the index is negative. //
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////  ////
    template<typename index_type>
    static void throw_index_negative(index_type index)
    {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << "index(" << index << ") < 0";
        throw std::runtime_error{ss.str()};
    }

    ////  ////////////////////////////////////////////////
     // Throws an exception if the index is too large. //
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////  ////
    template<typename index_type,
             typename element_count_type>
    static void throw_index_too_large(index_type index,
                                      element_count_type size)
    {
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << "index(" << index << ") >= elem_count(" << size << ")";
        throw std::runtime_error{ss.str()};
    }

    template<typename IteratorElem,
             typename IteratorIndex>
    static void check_indices(IteratorElem elem_begin,
                              IteratorElem elem_end,
                              IteratorIndex index_begin,
                              IteratorIndex index_end)
    {
        // Find the length of the element sequence:
        typename std::iterator_traits<IteratorElem>
                    ::difference_type elem_count = std::distance(elem_begin,
                                                                 elem_end);

        using IndexType =
        typename std::iterator_traits<IteratorIndex>::value_type;

        // Check that each index does not refer outside the element sequence:
        std::for_each(index_begin, index_end, [elem_count](IndexType index) {
            if (index < 0) { throw_index_negative(index); }
            if (index >= elem_count) { throw_index_too_large(index,
                                                             elem_count);}
        });
    }

    template<typename IteratorElem,
             typename IteratorIndex>
    std::vector<typename std::iterator_traits<IteratorElem>::value_type>
    multi_index(IteratorElem elem_begin,
                IteratorElem elem_end,
                IteratorIndex index_begin,
                IteratorIndex index_end)
    {
        check_indices(elem_begin,
                      elem_end,
                      index_begin,
                      index_end);

        using ElementType =
        typename std::iterator_traits<IteratorElem>::value_type;

        using IndexType =
        typename std::iterator_traits<IteratorIndex>::value_type;

        std::vector<ElementType> result;

        std::for_each(index_begin,
                      index_end,
                      [elem_begin, &result](IndexType index) {
            auto it = elem_begin;
            std::advance(it, index);
            result.push_back(*it);
        });

        return result;
    }
}

#endif // NET_CODERODDE_UTIL_MULTI_INDEX_HPP
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "multi_index.hpp"
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <vector>

using net::coderodde::util::multi_index;

static std::vector<char> get_alphabet() {
    std::vector<char> alphabet;

    for (char ch = 'a'; ch <= 'z'; ch++)
    {
        alphabet.push_back(ch);
    }

    for (char ch = 'A'; ch <= 'Z'; ch++)
    {
        alphabet.push_back(ch);
    }

    alphabet.push_back(',');
    alphabet.push_back(' ');
    alphabet.push_back('!');
    alphabet.push_back('\n');

    return alphabet;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    std::vector<char> alphabet = get_alphabet();
    std::list<int> char_indices =
        { 33, 4, 11, 11, 14, 52, 53, 48, 14, 17, 11, 3, 54, 55 };
    std::vector<char> result = multi_index(alphabet.cbegin(),
                                           alphabet.cend(),
                                           char_indices.cbegin(),
                                           char_indices.cend());

    std::ostream_iterator<char> out_iterator(std::cout);
    std::copy(result.cbegin(), result.cend(), out_iterator);

    try {
        char_indices = { 0, 1, 2, -1, 3 };
        multi_index(alphabet.cbegin(),
                    alphabet.cend(),
                    char_indices.cbegin(),
                    char_indices.cend());
    } catch (std::runtime_error& err) {
        std::cout << err.what() << "\n";
    }

    try {
        char_indices = { 0, 1, 2, 56, 3 };
        multi_index(alphabet.cbegin(),
                    alphabet.cend(),
                    char_indices.cbegin(),
                    char_indices.cend());
    } catch (std::runtime_error& err) {
        std::cout << err.what() << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Outputs:

> ```
> Hello, World!
> index(-1) < 0
> index(56) >= elem_count(56)
> ```

## Critique request

Please tell me anything that comes to mind. Also, I would like to hear about using move semantics: is there anything I could move instead of copying?

Comment: I was thrown off by your comment blocks for a second, thought there was an indenting issue. Then I noticed the Z patterns. Nice!

Comment: @Cris Luengo I should have removed them altogether.

Comment: A small notice about consistency. You define first "using index_type" and then "using IndexType" is there a reason for that? Sorry if I'm missing something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overall good, covers most of the usual usage cases.

### Ideology

Although the code certainly values some principles of standard library, I believe it is much easier used with libraries like POCO (which quite a lot of people believe is better), which have their own view of C++. There is a great idea struggling to come out, or at least illusion of it's existence. It is really hard to tell which one it is, though.

---

### Code

### Naming

What the code essentially performs is selective copying, so I would use `selective_copy` or `indexwise_copy`. Some people might get confused, but hopefully IDE popup with argument types will resolve it.

### More fluent interface

```
std::list<int> char_indices =
    { 33, 4, 11, 11, 14, 52, 53, 48, 14, 17, 11, 3, 54, 55 };
std::vector<char> result = multi_index(alphabet.cbegin(),
                                       alphabet.cend(),
                                       char_indices.cbegin(),
                                       char_indices.cend());
```

The example usage clearly shows that function needs `std::initializer_list<std::size_t>` overload.

### auto

I believe the function declaration could use auto:

```
template<typename IteratorElem,
         typename IteratorIndex>
auto multi_index(IteratorElem elem_begin,
                 IteratorElem elem_end,
                 IteratorIndex index_begin,
                 IteratorIndex index_end)
```

Most C++ programmers will by default assume `std::vector`. Pedantic people will just go through the code to discover correctness of their assumptions. No surprises.

And in `elem_count`:

```
auto elem_count = std::distance(elem_begin, elem_end);
```

### Hide helpers

I would hide the `throw_xxx` functions into `namespace detail` or similar.

### Minor things

```
        auto it = elem_begin;
        std::advance(it, index);
```

Can be written as `std::next(it, index);`.

I believe `std::transform` would be a better fit for the copying loop, but this is very subjective.

### Alternative approach

Another point of view, the one that emphasizes objects more than actions, would reveal different solution: `indirection_iterator`.

```
template <typename ForwardIterator>
class indirection_iterator
{
    std::vector<ForwardIterator> iterators;
public:
    //stuff to conform RandomAccessIterator
    //propagate dereference into underlying iterators
    // use decltype(auto) to propagate proxies, like from vector<bool>

private:
    //constructors
};

template <typename ForwardIterator>
std::pair<indirection_iterator<ForwardIterator>,
          indirection_iterator<ForwardIterator>>
create_indirection_range(/*...*/) //takes the same things as `selective_copy`
```

### Design decisions:

- Private constructors

  There is no valid iterator which will be usable by creating only one iterator. The only cases are usages like `doxxx_n` algorithms. Having the second one is free anyway, and in C++17 people can just:

  ```
  auto [first, last] = create_indirection_range(...);
  ```
- Random access iterator

  It doesn't seem like there is a reason to impose different behavior. Don't use `ContiguousIterator` though, as the iterator is not aware of layout of objects in memory.

### Overview of alternative solution

It looks like it solves many problems. One can now sort lists, forward lists, and whatnot. One can even write functions like this:

```
using indirection_range = ...; //the pair above

indirection_range all_except(Range range, Iterator to_leave_out);
```

Now one can leave out an element or many of them, and then sort the rest as if the range was contiguous.

But it is not a panacea. It looks like an iterator, it even compiles, and this is one of the fundamental problems: it pretends to be an iterator. Actual iterators are cheap to copy. In fact, most of the time it is a pointer. `indirection_iterator` violates this assumption. Any divide and conquer algorithms will pass iterators down the recursion chain, as a result somewhat degrading the efficiency of algorithms.

Throwing away other minor problems, `indirection_iterator might have its niche usages, but I don't think it is the-day-to-day iterator to use.

To date, I believed that there is C++ way of doing things. But now I just think that it is yet another point of view, and not something absolute, like a fact. Unfortunately, IMO, people are very bad at communicating and learning facts, as human language and any medium through which it is delivered usually causes some bias in human's perception.

Comment: A question: is there is any chance that in C++17 people can write `(obj1, obj2).methodFoo(...);`, where `obj1` and `obj2` are of the same type supporting method `methodFoo`?

Comment: @coderodde, what behavior should it have? Return a tuple? I'm not sure I understand the question. I guess you want to call a function of N objects which share the same interface? From the look of it I'd say no, but something similar is easy to write.

Comment: Yes, basically, call `obj1.methodFoo(...)` and then `obj2.methodFoo(...);`, both with same arguments.

Comment: @coderodde, if you'll need input arguments too, then it will be a little tricky. The only possible syntax I can think of is `call(member_f, pack(objects...), arguments...);`, Also calling `pack` outside will probably cause undefined behavior, as it must support temporaries too. More concrete example would be better. There is a C++ questions and answers chat room on SO, there we could have more interactive conversation and not flood the comments.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can simplify your code a bit, which is always a good thing.

You can generate the alphabet in a cleaner way by using the appropriate standard algorithm:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
int main() {
    std::vector<char> alphabet;
    auto alpha = 'a';
    std::generate_n(std::back_inserter(alphabet), 26, [&alpha]() { return alpha++; });
}
```

A dedicated function to apply the indices on the vector is a bit of overkill also, and the for range is cleaner than for_each when you iterate over the whole sequence:

```
for (auto idx : indices) result.push_back(alphabet[idx]);
```

You can't really use the generic approach because your algorithm would be extremely inefficient with anything else than a random access iterator -so it's better to simply use the subscript operator.

As to `check_indices` I think you can leverage the `any_of` algorithm:

```
auto out_of_bound = std::any_of(std::begin(char_indices), std::end(char_indices),
                               [&alphabet](auto&& idx) {
                                     return idx < 0 || idx >= alphabet.size();
                                                       });
```

It's also good to know that you can get away without throwing exceptions. There's this new `std::optional` now to take into account the impossiblity of returning any sensible value. The caller can then decide how to act upon the failure. So for example:

```
std::optional<std::vector<char>> multi_index(/* insert args here*/);
```

and then

```
auto msg = multi_index(f1, l1, f2, l2);
if (msg.has_value()) display(*msg);
else std::cout << "please provide correct indices";
```

Comment: Instead of generate, you can use iota

Comment: @Incomputable Yes, better stil

Comment: Can you use `if (msg)`? That should work no?

Comment: @Haddad Just a personal preference, I like to see at first glance it isn't a pointer.

Comment: Damn, nice code! so much cool stuff

Comment: "*generate the alphabet in a cleaner way*" - only if the target character encoding has contiguous `a`..`z` (not EBCDIC, for instance).  And I'd prefer `'z'-'a'` to that literal `26` even then!  Perhaps `std::iota` would be better than `generate_n` (and `std::array<char, 'z'-'a'>` better than `std::vector<char>`).

Comment: Er, I obviously meant `'z'-'a'+1` above!  Or better, `static constexpr size_t alphabet_length = 'z'-'a'+1;` and then use it by name.